# How to include the spin-orbit coupling strength of only two or three elements in VASP?

Tags: vasp, spin-orbit-coupling, reproducing-data-from-papers

I am trying to calculate magnetic properties in my material with VASP, much like Fig 3b of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.100.134438). The paper says:

> "To understand the origin of the SIAin monolayer MnBi2Te4, we performed the atom-resolved SIA calculations by changing the SOC strength of the atoms separately. As shown in Fig.3(a), when we take into account only one kind of the element’s SOC, the SIA is much smaller than that in the real situation (denoted by the black line). In other words, the SOC of each element alone cannot cause the SIA. Actually, the SIA mainly originates from the joint SOC effect of Mn and Te atoms, because the calculated SIA approaches the correct value only when the SOC of the Mn and Te atoms is considered simultaneously [see Fig.3(b)]."

[image]

**How do I calculate the curves that only involve Bi and Te, or Bi and Mn, or Mn and Te, for example?**

The paper says: "Our DFT calculations were performed using the Viennaab initiosimulation package (VASP)"

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you so much for contributing your question here, and we hope to see much more of you in the future! I'm having trouble understanding your question though: The title says that you want to **change** the SOC strength of two or three elements, and the body of your question says that you want to **maintain**  the SOC of two elements. Can you be more specific about what you want?

Comment: Also you might be interested in this: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9494/5 and this: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4657/5 and the rest of these: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spin-orbit-coupling+vasp

Comment: [I've tried to help get this question answered for you](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9494/soc-calculations-in-vasp/9498?noredirect=1#comment20922_9498) but that user (who knows a decent amount about SOC in VASP) is also confused about what you're asking. That means at least two of us are confused, so I suggest that you clarify the question ASAP so it doesn't get any close votes!

Comment: Thanks. I want to close the SOC of the other elements and only maintain the SOC of two selected elements, like PHYSICAL REVIEW B 100, 134438 (2019) Fig3(b), in this figure, the authors calculated 2 different kinds of the elements’ SOC and close the others'.

Comment: What do you mean by "close" the SOC?

Comment: Only consider two kinds of the element’s SOC, the other elements do not have SOC

Comment: I didn't see your last comment, because you didn't ping me. That's very unfortunate because you did reply right away, and now it's more than 6 months later. Maybe I need to click "Follow" every time, so that new users who have never seen the ping feature, don't miss out. Anyway, since you haven't been online since you asked this, I flagged for the post to get closed as abandoned, but I'll "follow" the post in case you do reply letting us know that you see this!